# PyQt5 ToolBar onclick function

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtoolbar

I am a beginner in python and I want to start with a simple GUI.
I use PyQt5 for gui development.

I want run itWorks() if the user click the Login Toolbar Button.
Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QAction, qApp, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

class Main(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):               

        exitAct = QAction(QIcon('images/Login.ico'), 'Login', self)
        #exitAct.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAct.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)#why i cant run my function here?

        self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('Exit')
        self.toolbar.addAction(exitAct)

        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 600, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle('Toolbar')    
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Main()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

function:

```
def itWorks():
   print("it works")
```

thanky for your help

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been asked more than a year ago, but i went into the same issue and mange to solve it. so here is an example of creating a "Tool Bar" and get the action/event.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
import sys


class TestClass(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    """TestClass Implementation"""
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(200, 100)

    def run(self):
        # Adding tool bar to the window
        toolBar = self.addToolBar("")

        # Creating Items for the tool-bar
        folderOpen = QtWidgets.QAction(QtGui.QIcon("add_pack.ico"), "Open Folder", toolBar)
        newDoc = QtWidgets.QAction("New Documents", toolBar)
        tools = QtWidgets.QAction("Tools", toolBar)

        # Adding those item into the tool-bar
        toolBar.addAction(folderOpen)
        toolBar.addAction(newDoc)
        toolBar.addAction(tools)

        # Setting the action/event on the entire tool-bar, setting a function to call to.
        toolBar.actionTriggered[QtWidgets.QAction].connect(self.whoGotSelected)
        self.show()

    def whoGotSelected(self, selection):
        # Getting the selected button obj, taking the given text name.
        name = selection.text()

        # Print the name selected.
        print(f"Tool-Bar |{name}| is selected")

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    test = TestClass()
    test.run()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

outputs are:

Tool-Bar |Open Folder| is selected

Tool-Bar |New Documents| is selected

Tool-Bar |Tools| is selected

Here is how it looks like

[image]

I added an .ico just for usage example, if you run it on you system when you don't have the file, it will work, and it will show an empty square.